How to deal with Spring State Machine resetting after restore from database?
My goal: configure State Machine to persist internal data at any changes, restore from DB when I need to use it.
Realisation: Spring Docs
Problem: It works fine at one start (saving to db and restoring). After restart, state machine resets to initial (with losing all data) at first usage.
Relevant State machine config:
@EnableStateMachineFactory
@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
public class StateMachineConfig extends StateMachineConfigurerAdapter<ConversationState, BotEvent> {
private final StateMachineRuntimePersister<ConversationState, BotEvent, String> stateMachineRuntimePersister;

    @Bean
    public StateMachineService<ConversationState, BotEvent> stateMachineService(
            StateMachineFactory<ConversationState, BotEvent> stateMachineFactory,
            StateMachineRuntimePersister<ConversationState, BotEvent, String> stateMachineRuntimePersister) {
        return new DefaultStateMachineService<ConversationState, BotEvent>(stateMachineFactory, stateMachineRuntimePersister);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(StateMachineConfigurationConfigurer<ConversationState, BotEvent> config) throws Exception {
        config.withConfiguration()
                .listener(listener())
                .autoStartup(true)
                .and()
                .withPersistence().runtimePersister(stateMachineRuntimePersister)
        ;
    }
// states, transitions, actions etc. config...
}

@Configuration
public class JpaPersisterConfig {
    @Bean
    public StateMachineRuntimePersister<ConversationState, BotEvent, String> stateMachineRuntimePersister(
            JpaStateMachineRepository jpaStateMachineRepository) {
        return new JpaPersistingStateMachineInterceptor<>(jpaStateMachineRepository);
    }
}

Usage:
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SomeClass{
    private StateMachineService<ConversationState, BotEvent> stateMachineService;

    public void someMethod(String userId) {
        StateMachine<ConversationState, BotEvent> stateMachine = restoreStateMachine(userId);
        // work with stateMachine, sending events
    }
}

